# User with global privileges on VSFTPD / Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, sftp, vsftpd

I'm running VSFTPD on Ubuntu 18.04 in a VPS server.

I added a user to www-data group Set user home directory for /var/www

I'd like to login with this user on ftp/sftp and that's mainly for notepad++ so I could edit any content under /var/www including virtual hosts files...

I can't login with nppFTP plugin in notepad++ and neither on Filezilla!

Only when I was editing vsftpd.conf with terminal I managed to login through notepad++ but it only showed me /var/www folder' content.

I would be thankful for any tips or a functional vsftpd.conf allowing superadmin full access via ftp/sftp

P. S: I already enabled common ports in ufw. And been able to verify accessibility for this user in ftp terminal.

Comment: (1) What do you mean by "I'd like to login with this user on ftp/sftp and that's mainly for notepad++" and "I managed to login through notepad++"?  (2) What do you mean by "it only showed me /var/www folder content" and "full access with read/write permissions on all /var/www content"? … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

It was relied to connection mode and encoding!
I had to set Active Mode in Transfers settings and force utf-8 encoding

The mess was on client side. Hope it could be helpful to someone